# How do I add a Maven pom.xml to an existing project without using an IDE?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have an existing Java project with a single dependency. I just want to make a pom.xml so that someone can pull the project, `mvn install` or `mvn init` or whatever it is, then start working. How do I do this without using an IDE?

I'm looking for the equivalent of `pip freeze` or `npm init`, or just what I can copy and paste into a new `pom.xml` file.

I tried Googling and only found stuff for starting new projects with Maven or using an Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow suggested three steps to convert your project into maven project.

**Step 1:**
As suggested by [nullpointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42685734/7212399), following attributes are mandatory in your pom to make it as maven project.

[Sample pom.xml file](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.infy</groupId>
    <artifactId>user-identity-rest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</project>
```

**groupId**: It is unique identifier to the group of multiple modules in your project

**artifactId**: Unique module identifier of your module.

**version**: Initially we will start with version 1.0.0 and will upgrade to 1.0.1 and so on subsequently.

You can customized these things as per your understanding and future references.

**Step 2:**
Now you need to add all libraries in declared pom.xml which is similar to jars you added in your project.

You might have added a library in your project(lets say json-simple-1.1.1.jar). Here maven doesn't look for the whole library, instead it asks its dependency.

You can find dependency of your external library [here](https://mvnrepository.com) by searching for library with [exact version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you need to copy the dependency from [given site](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1) and paste it to your pom.xml file within the `<dependencies>` element. In this example, the full pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.infy</groupId>
    <artifactId>user-identity-rest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
             <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
             <version>1.1.1</version>
         </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Maven will automatically fetch it from its repository.

**Step 3:**
Third and last step is to build your project. Open command prompt/terminal and go to the directory where your pom.xml is declared and type **mvn clean install**

[image: Building application with maven]

This will generate an executable for your project on local and voilla! You have converted and built your project into maven project

Reference Path: C:\PA\IntelliJ Workspace\Springboot Practise\target\spring-boot-examples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

**Note:** Comment below if you need more clarifications.

Comment: I need to include dependencies from my local machine itself how to mention it in pom file.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be looking for a [Minimal POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Minimal_POM) for your project. This is defined as -

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</project>
```

where you can replace the names more convenient to your `group` and `artifact`. Just a small note to take care of -

> ..if the configuration details are not specified, Maven will use their
>   defaults.

Comment: can I avoid using `src/main/java` project structure altogether?

Answer (score 1):

You can let Maven create the `pom.xml` and directory structure for you auomatically with this command:

```
$ mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=ca.leif -DartifactId=HelloWorld -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

But just replace the `groupId` and `artifactId` with your own values.

Then put your `.java` files in `/src/main/java/ca/leif`.

And then run the standard commands like `mvn compile`, `mvn clean`, `mvn package`.

[Source](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/).

Comment: What if I don't want to be using the `/src/main/java/` project structure ?

Comment: It's possible. Read about a custom `<sourceDirectory>` here https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html

Comment: Thanks Leif. Actually, what I exactly want is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49042329/eclipse-how-to-bypass-using-standard-directory-structures-in-maven